# Как сделать цикл отправки сообщений от бота на Python

Tags: python, telebot

Как сделать цикл, что бы бот сам присылал сообщение пользователю, например каждый час он будет присылать сообщение о времени в Москве. Код Python с pytelegrambotapi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PyTelegramBotApi` это синхронный `python`.
Можно с помощю функции `sleep` заставить бота делать что-то в нужное время.

С помощю `datetime` посчитать сколько секунд нужно ждать до завтра.

```py
now = datetime.now()
# добовляем текущей дате один день
to = now + timedelta(days=1)
# заменяем час, минуту и секунду
to = to.replace(hour=10, minute=30, second=0)
# секунд до завтра в 10:30
seconds_to_wait = (to - now).total_seconds()
```

Потом сделать `sleep(seconds_to_wait)` а сразу после отправить сообщение. **Но бот до завтра в 10:30 будет неактивен**.

Врядли это то, что тебе нужно. Переходи на `aiogram` и асинхронный `python`.

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

API_TOKEN = ''

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

chat_ids = {}

@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    chat_ids[message.from_user.id] = message.from_user
    text = f'{message.message_id} {message.from_user} {message.text}'
    await message.reply(text, reply=False)

async def periodic(sleep_for):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(sleep_for)
        now = datetime.utcnow()
        print(f"{now}")
        for id in chat_ids:
            await bot.send_message(id, f"{now}", disable_notification=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dp.loop.create_task(periodic(10))
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Источник https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59502355/how-to-integrate-custom-task-into-aiogram-executor